# How to address python code-browsing and code-completion issues in vim?

Tags: python, ruby, vim, code-completion

I'm working on a large python project using vim with tagexplorer, pythoncomplete, and ctags. Tag-based code-browsing and code-completion features don't work the way they should unfortunately because ctags doesn't tie instances to types.

Hypothetical scenarios:

- Auto Complete: vim won't auto-complete method `on()` in `myCar.ignition().on()` because ctags doesn't know that `ignition()` returns `TypeIgnition`.
- Code Browsing: vim won't browse into `TypeCar` when I click on `myCar` but instead presents me with multiple definition matches, incorrect matches, or no matches because ctags doesn't backtrack and tie instances to types.

The problem seems to stem from python being a dynamically typed language. Neither scenario  would present a challenge otherwise.  **Is there an effective alternative to tags-based code-browsing and code-completion and an IDE or vim plugin that implements it well?**

**Note:** Please vote "re-open". Solutions to this problem are valuable to the community. The question was originally formulated very vaguely, that's no longer the case.

Comment: `s/weak typing/dynamic typing/`

Comment: I found [spyder](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/) on SO about a week ago. Might take a look at how they do some of their stuff.

Comment: I don't consider this a major issue.  I sometimes use [ropemacs](http://rope.sourceforge.net/ropemacs.html) for auto-expansion, which works well.  Usually I simply type the attribute names, though, and I don't feel it's getting in the way of productivity.  If I would, I'd certainly make more use of ropemacs.

Comment: Voted reopen on this one. I think it's pretty well defined as a question ('does there exist something that does X') and an answer to this may be useful.

Comment: @delnan could you please explain your comment, I'm curious.

Comment: @johnthexiii The original post spoke of "weak typing" regarding Python and Ruby. I suggested changing that to "dynamic typing", as "weak typing" is ill-defined and most definitions are unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Commercial IDE for python like wing (www.wingware.com) and pycharm (www.jetbrains.com/pycharm) are better to solve majority of code-completion issues. Of course, they are not free though. I myself, when use eclipse with pydev plugin was not able to get satisfactory results.

Comment: shucks, I was about to try PyDev

Comment: I would encourage you to try it. My problem with Pydev was when I imported third party library. There are lots of bugs yet to be addressed in PyDev but it is definitely better than the IDE with which python comes.

Comment: PyDev works pretty well.  Far from perfect, but pretty damn well.  And what you lose in code completion is somewhat made up for in the ability to break in to your code at any point at run time and execute arbitrary code in the active frame.